# c++ error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'WindLogType' and 'double')

Tags: c++

This is homework. So anyways, the exercise requires the user to read the csv file, use the data inside (Wind Speed) via a Template Vector class to perform calculations, and display average wind speed as well as some other stuff. The problem lies in how I read the file into the vector class to perform the calculations.

I've been semi-successful, using getline and stringstream to isolate the particular value (it's after 10 commas). The problem is when I try to use the value with the Template Vector class. Certain things like push_back() and size() works, but at() and print() face issues.

```
// included all the necessary .h and <> here
typedef struct
{
    Date d;
    Time t;
    float speed;
} WindLogType;

// declare speed max function (I just realised I have no idea what this was for)
ostream & operator << (ostream & osObject, const WindLogType & W1);
istream & operator >> (istream & input, WindLogType & W1);

int main()
{
    // Declared a lot of variables here etc.

    Vector <WindLogType> windlog;

    WindLogType transfer; // Declaring an object of WindLogType

    while(getline(input, line))
    {
        stringstream line2(line);
        string cell; // Denotes a particular column
        int col = 0;

        while(getline(line2, cell, ','))
        {
            if(col == 10)
            {
                speed = atof(cell.c_str()); // Converting to c-string, and 
                                            // then float

                transfer.speed = speed; // Inputting wind speed into 
                                        // WindLogType speed

                windlog.push_back(transfer);
            }
            col++;
        }
    }

    // Sum of all the wind speeds
    for(int i = 0; i < windlog.size(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + (windlog.at(i) * 3.6); // Converting every elements to 
                                           // km/h
    }

    average = sum/windlog.size(); // Average wind speed
    cout << average;

    while(input.eof())
    {
        ...;
    }

    // Printing out date and time of speeds that be equal to the average
    for(int j = 0; j < windlog.size(); j++)
    {
        if(windlog.at(j) == average)
        {
            ...;
        }
    }

    input.close();
}

// In the Template Vector Class
template <class Type>
class Vector
{
   Type *list;
   int length; // The number of arrays of a current vector.
   void push_back(const Type& i);
   ...; // Everything else
}

template <class Type>
Type& Vector<Type>::at(int i)
{
    if((i >= 0) && (i < length))
    {
        return list[i];
    }

    return list[0];
}
```

I expect `sum = sum + (windlog.at(i) * 3.6)` or `if(windlog.at(j) == average)` to work, but it returns `error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'WindLogType' and 'double')`.

So is how I read the csv file into the vector the issue?

Comment: `windlog.at(i) * 3.6` You probably meant `windlog[i].speed * 3.6`

Comment: Just tried it, gives me ```error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Vector<WindLogType>' and 'int')|``` instead

Comment: `typedef struct { ...} WindLogType;` is slightly bizarre. Why not just `struct WindLogType { ... };`?

Comment: `windlog.at(i).speed * 3.6`, then. I didn't realize that `windlog` is some custom `Vector` and not a plain vanilla `std::vector`

Comment: It's a weird assignment, the whole ```typedef struct {} WindLogType``` chunk was explicitly told to be part of the code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Dude! You just blew my mind! I can't believe I spent the whole day doing this :O

Comment: When you get an error message, you need to try to figure out why the compiler thinks there's an error. It says that it doesn't know how to multiply a `WindLogType` and a `double`. Did you intend to multiply a `WindLogType` and a `double`? If so, then you need to say how you multiply it with a `double`. If you didn't intend to multiply a `WindLogType` and a `double`, then what *did* you intend to multiply?